# Регулярное выражение для вендорных префиксов css

Tags: css, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите, как правильно создать регулярное выражение?
чтобы более понятней была суть проблемы, приведу пример допустим с css-кодом.
Нужно из `css` вырезать вендорные префиксы, к примеру такие:

```
-webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
-moz-transform: translateY(100%);
-o-transform: translateY(100%);
```

использую такое регулярное выражение в phpstorm: `-(o|webkit|moz|ms)-[^{;]*?;`
но сюда также попадают и такие, которые нужно оставить:
 `background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45), transparent 47%);`
или
`display: -webkit-box;`
`line-height: -moz-block-height;`
в результате могут быть некорректные стили после вырезания:
 `background:display:line-height:`

т.е. нужно предусмотреть, если перед этим выражением `-(o|webkit|moz|ms)-` есть что-то типа двоеточия с пробелом (`...ground: -o-linear...`), то пропустить, не удалять.
это выражение не подходит:
`(?!:\s)-(o|webkit|moz|ms)-[^{;]+?;`
т.е. `(?!:\s)` - отрицание наличия символов

**P.S.**
**input**

```
.wrap.style-3 .content-wrap {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -moz-transform: translateY(-50%);
    -o-transform: translateY(-50%);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.header-top-panel:before, .header-top-panel:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
.wrap.style-3 .content-wrap {position: relative;top: 50%;-webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);-moz-transform: translateY(-50%);-o-transform: translateY(-50%);transform: translateY(-50%);}
img{-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic;}
fieldset{border:solid 1px #e7e7e7;-webkit-border-radius:3px;-moz-border-radius:3px;-ms-border-radius:3px;-o-border-radius:3px;border-radius:3px;padding:12px;margin:18px 0;}
row-content-top{display:-webkit-box;display:-webkit-flex;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;-webkit-box-align:flex-start;-webkit-align-items:flex-start;-ms-flex-align:flex-start;align-items:flex-start;box-sizing:border-box;}
```

**output**

```
.wrap.style-3 .content-wrap {
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.header-top-panel:before, .header-top-panel:after {
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
.wrap.style-3 .content-wrap {position: relative;top: 50%;transform: translateY(-50%);}
img{}
fieldset{border:solid 1px #e7e7e7;border-radius:3px;padding:12px;margin:18px 0;}
row-content-top{display:-webkit-box;display:-webkit-flex;display:-ms-flexbox;display:flex;align-items:flex-start;box-sizing:border-box;}
```

т.е. под регулярное выражение должны подходить строки, начинающиеся с приставки
 (-webkit-|-moz-|-ms-|-o-) до закрывающей кавычки `;`, к примеру:

```
-webkit-transform: translateY(100%);
-moz-transform: translateY(100%);
-o-transform: translateY(100%);
```

Но это правило css: `display: -webkit-box;` не должно подходить под регулярное выражение (оно также начинается с префикса, но перед ним есть двоеточие), потому-что после вырезания будет некорректный css-код, (`display:display:display:`)
т.е. нужно в рег. выражении предусмотреть, что если перед приставкой (-webkit-|-moz-|-ms-|-o-) есть двоеточие, тогда это не должно подходить, т.к. после вырезания будет некорректный css-код

Comment: @Эдуард подскажите, а что означает это `(?:-(\pL+))`, хотелось-бы понять работу с этим выражением? и кстати не работает это выражение

Comment: `(?:-(\pL+)){2}:[^;]+;-(o|webkit|moz|ms)-[^{;]+?;` это не работает. Как правильно его использовать объясните пожалуйста?

Comment: @Эдуард, посмотрите пож-ста, https://regex101.com/r/39rcik/3, ваше выражение вырезает правила стилей, в которых вообще нет префиксов, в результате стили ломаются, нужно чётко определить, чтобы вырезать только правила css, в которых есть префиксы

Comment: @Эдуард, обновил https://regex101.com/r/39rcik/6, тут нужно учитывать специфику css, ваш код не работает

Comment: @Эдуард, нет не всё учитывает, https://regex101.com/r/39rcik/12

Comment: `(?<!:\s)-(?:o|webkit|moz|ms)-[^;\n]+;`? https://regex101.com/r/HZDcJl/1

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, что-то похожее, но в последней строке вырезается лишнее, в результате это некорректный css-код: `row-content-top{display:display:display:display:flex;align-items:flex-start;box-sizing:border-box;}`

Comment: т.е. `{display:display:display:` это неправильно

Comment: должно быть так: `row-content-top{display:flex;align-items:flex-start;box-sizing:border-box;}`

Comment: display: нужно также вырезать, но вместо display может быть что угодно, к примеру: `background: -o-linear-gradient` как показано выше в задаче

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Есть строка, что надо *найти*? Регулярки не удаляют, не "вырезают", они только находят соответствия шаблону в тексте. Добавьте конкретный пример в вопрос и ожидаемый результат.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, добавил в вопрос дополнение, я ничего не говорил про вырезать с помощью рег. выражения

Comment: *Но это правило css display: `-webkit-box;` не должно подходить под регулярное выражение, потому-что после вырезания будет некорректный css-код, (`display:display:display:`)* - т.е. что нужно с точки зрения регулярного выражения?

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, в последних 2х моих комментариях я неправильно сказал про display, в задачу добавил это, т.е. это должно остаться: `display:-webkit-box;`, а это нужно вырезать (вырезать я буду сам, имеется ввиду, должно подходить под регулярное выражение): `-moz-transform: translateY(100%);`, потому-что перед этим `-moz-transform` нет двоеточия

Comment: `(?<!:)(?<!:\s)-(?:webkit|moz|ms|o)-[^;]*;`? https://regex101.com/r/9oRqrB/1

Comment: `:\s*(-(?:webkit|moz|ms|o)-[^;]*;)(*SKIP)(*F)|(?1)`? https://regex101.com/r/9oRqrB/2

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, это подходит, благодарю (?<!:)(?<!:\s)-(?:webkit|moz|ms|o)-[^;]*;

Comment: объясните пож-ста, что это значит? `(?<!:)(?<!:\s)-(?:webki`

Comment: и почему такой вариант не работал? `(?!:\s)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(?!:\s)` — блок предварительного просмотра вперёд, он находит позицию, сразу *после* которой нет двоеточия и пробельного символа. Вы можете использовать блоки предварительного просмотра *назад*:

```
/(?<!:)(?<!:\s)-(?:webkit|moz|ms|o)-[^;]*;/
```

См. [демо онлайн](https://regex101.com/r/9oRqrB/1).

**Подробности**

- `(?<!:)` - блок предварительного просмотра назад, сразу перед текущей позицией не должно быть двоеточия
- `(?<!:\s)` - блок предварительного просмотра назад, сразу перед текущей позицией не должно быть двоеточия и пробельного символа
- `-` - дефис
- `(?:webkit|moz|ms|o)` - незахватывающая подмаска, находит строки `webkit`, `moz`, `ms`, `o`
- `-` - дефис
- `[^;]*` - ноль и более символов, отличных от точки с запятой
- `;` - точка с запятой.

Comment: а подскажите плиз, почему не срабатывает только это `(?<!:\s)` ? для чего нужно два выражения? `(?<!:)(?<!:\s)`

Comment: @word `(?<!:)(?<!:\s)` = `(?<!:\s?)` Лучше тут, конечно, использовать `(?<!:\s*)`. Просто в большинстве случаев такие блоки просмотра назад недействительны. Всё зависит от конкретной реализации регулярных выражений, поэтому вы должны были указать язык программирования, на котором пишете код. Так бы вы получили точный ответ  гораздо раньше и без дополнительных вопросов.

Comment: `(?<!:\s*)-(?:webkit|moz|ms|o)-[^;]*;` это не подходит, для чего два выражения?.и по вопросу языка, ну если из первоначального варианта `(?!:\s)-(o|webkit|moz|ms)-[^{;]+?;`  мало было информации про используемый язык (pcre) извиняюсь. разве другие виды регулярок настолько похожи?, не знал это

Comment: [Тут](http://regexstorm.net/tester) это выражение очень даже подходит. В PCRE лучше пользоваться [`:\s*(-(?:webkit|moz|ms|o)-[^;]*;)(*SKIP)(*F)|(?1)`](https://regex101.com/r/9oRqrB/2).